# Show toast notification after reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to show the a toast notification after the page is reloaded that says that the file is uploaded. This is what I got so far

```
_fileUploads.delete = function(reload_on_return) {
  var filtered = root.fileUploads().filter(_ => _._id() == _fileUploads._id());
  var index = root.fileUploads.indexOf(filtered = filtered[0]);
  filtered = ko.toJS(filtered);

  swal({
    text: 'Are you sure you want to delete this file?',
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
    icon: 'warning'
  }).then(function (allowDelete) {
    if (allowDelete) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/api/gridfs/files/' + filtered._id,
        statusCode: {
          204: function(response) {
            toastrTrigger('The File has been Deleted')
            if (reload_on_return) {
              setTimeout( function() {
                location.reload();
              }, 0001);    
            }
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(xhr);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

This only refreshes the page and not show the notification

This is the toastrtrigger function()

```js
function toastrTrigger(message, title, type) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    toastr.options = {
      closeButton: true,
      progressBar: true,
      showMethod: 'slideDown',
      timeOut: 4000
    };
    toastr[type || "success"](message, title || 'File Uploads Repository');
  }, 500);
}
```

Comment: What is `toastrTrigger`? Are you expecting it to *block* like an alert? Can you share its code?

Comment: yes, it is a function on my script. It is something like that. Here is the link to the toaster alerts github : https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Comment: Can you post your `toastrTrigger` function itself? Pretty sure that's needed in order to figure out a solution

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated the post It has the function. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scripts do not persist *after* the page has been reloaded: once the document is closed, all scripts associated with the document go away with it. There's no way around that. You'll have to somehow pass information to the page you navigate to purely through the URL.

One solution is to pass a query string to the reloaded page:

```
if (reload_on_return) {
  window.location.href = window.location.pathname + '?deleteSuccess=1';
}
```

Then, on the same page, on page load, do a check to see if a query string are present:

```
const { search } = window.location;
const deleteSuccess = (new URLSearchParams(search)).get('deleteSuccess');
if (deleteSuccess === '1') {
  // The page was just reloaded, display the toast:
  toastrTrigger('The file has been deleted');
}
```

Another solution is to save the data in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead, and retrieve data from sessionStorage on page load to identify whether a notification should be displayed.

Comment: Thanks Working great